# Java String splitting difference between "|" and "\|"

Tags: java, string, split

yesterday I was stuck at splitting String with Java by a pipe '|'.

For example: I have a `String toSplitt = "Aa|Bb";` which I'd like to split.
The desired output should be:

```
Aa
Bb
```

When I do `String[] sp = toSplit.split("|");` and run the method to show the output:

```
for(String s : sp)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I get this:

```
A
a
```

After many attempts I got an idea to insert an escape character '\' at the left side of the pipe:

`toSplit.split("\\|");` and I got the desired output.

But now the problem is to split a String by a pipe without an escape char? I didn't know that a pipe is a char what should be escaped, isn't it?

I thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Do you mean `toSplit.split("\\|")`? Just `"\|"` wouldn't compile.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for this advice. Of course I mean toSplit.split("\\|");